# SQL query without aggregates

Tags: sql, optimization, aggregate

So I'm tasked with writing a few SQL queries that involve finding the highest or lowest value in a grouping without using aggregate functions. For example, I have the following table:

Ages:

```
Name        Age
John        21
Bill        30
Laura       19
Timothy     23
Victoria    29
```

Say I wanted to query the oldest person in the table (in this case Bill) without using aggregate functions (i.e. count, group, etc...)

**EDIT I also cannot use groupings in my queries! I didn't make that distinction very clear in my first post, my apologies =/**

I'm having trouble getting past:

```
SELECT name
FROM Ages
WHERE Ages.Age IN (
SELECT a1.Age
FROM Age a1, Age a2
WHERE a1.Age > a2.Age);
```

Obviously my query is no good here... I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of a useful SQL function or piece of logic that might help me with this type of query.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about ORDER BY? In case you need a single result, then just use an output limit or rowcount (.. where rownum<=1.. for oracle, ... limit 1... for mysql, etc).

Comment: Btw, group by is not an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in most DBMS:

```
select * from t
where age >= all (select age from t)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d471/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Name, Age
FROM...
ORDER BY Age ASC


SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  Name, Age
FROM...
ORDER BY Age DESC
```

Comment: I prefer the subquery solution since if there was a tie based on age, your query would only show ONE of the rows instead of both

Comment: @JNK  You could add [with ties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to take care of that. And I guess this will only work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any restriction using analytical functions you can use this.

```
select Name, 
       Age
from
  (
    select Name,
           Age,
           rank() over(order by Age desc) rn
    from Ages
  ) T
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries for this, and the `ORDER BY` operation.  `TOP` is valid for SQL Server but not for all RDBMS:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Ages
WHERE Age = (SELECT Top 1 AGE
             FROM Ages
             ORDER BY AGE DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a very weird requirement (can't use aggregates), so I have a very weird solution:

```
select name,
(select top 1 age from your_table where name=MAIN.name order by age desc) as older,
(select top 1 age from your_table where name=MAIN.name order by age) as newer
from your_table MAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
select * from t
where not exists (
  select * from t as t2
  where t2.age > t.age
) or not exists (
  select * from t as t2
  where t2.age < t.age
)
```